# Razor Mediator - Get Last Modifed Date of Component?

Tags: 2011, razormediator

Can I get to the last modified date of a component from a Razor template?

Update:  I found the answer:  Component.TridionObject.RevisionDate

Comment: So you now have two choices. 1) Put that as an answer and accept it. 2) Delete the question. Answering your own question is fine. Just apply the same criteria you would if you were thinking about anyone else's question.

Comment: Seems like this might be helpful for someone, so I opted for #1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer: `Component.TridionObject.RevisionDate`